# The toy was the best and built last year. Is a second "was" necessary to create "was built"?

Tags: verb-agreement, passive-voice, clauses, repetition, conjunction-reduction

Which of the below sentences is grammatically correct?

(A) The toy was the best and built last year.

(B) The toy was the best and was built last year.

I believe that sentence (B) is correct, but is the repetition of "was" truly necessary? In my mind, the "was" in sentence (A) applies to both the adjective ("best") and adds the passive voice to the past participle ("built"). Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Would "The best toy was built last year" still meet your requirements?

Comment: I can't find a source to reference, but in my mind, a "linking" *to be* ought not be asked to do double duty as an "auxiliary" *to be* in a passive construction. Use *was* twice.

Comment: @TinfoilHat - I'd say it was a matter of whether the Conjunction Reduction rule required identity of auxiliary function. As you note, the auxiliary _be_ required for predicate adjectives can be considered different from the auxiliary _be_ required for the passive construction.  Many people wouldn't notice; others would. To be sure, don't delete the second _was_.

Comment: Option A is confusing.

Comment: In practical terms, you have a short sentence that goes in two directions where you wonder if one verb can take you both places. No. You can swim in the summer and in the city, but swim in the summer and the city? Same. This is like a parallelism issue. You can have: The toy was judged the best and built just last year.

Comment: After listening to John Lawler, I'll stick my neck out and say that (A) is 25% unacceptable (but (B) is grammatically fine). But as is often the case, neither sentence sounds like something I'd choose to use. 'Toy X was the best to appear on the market in years; it appeared only last year, but seems to have been around for far longer.'

Answer (score 1):

I don't think such questions necessarily come down to 'wrong vs. right'. I would refuse to edit either sentence without seeing the full context, and then I'd most likely not use either formulation.

'was the best' begs the question 'best what?'. 'built last year' makes me wonder whether 'built' is the best choice of verb here. Toys are usually 'made', not 'built'. And 'which toy?'. Without context this question is rather pointless.

However in terms of the question you have two statements  which are possibly correlated, but again without context it's not possible to judge. 'The toy was the best' and 'The toy was built last year' could be two entirely unrelated statements, but then again maybe not. If there was a competition where most of the entrants where made in, say, the 1960s, then the fact 'it was built last year', may have some relevance to 'being the best', whereas if all of the entrants were made in the last five years, it should be considered a non sequitur in this sentence.

So for example 'The Steiff bear, made continuously since 1902, was selected as the winner of "Toy of the year"' makes perfect sense, and uses a parenthetical phrase (delimited by commas) to convey the relevant but ultimately unnecessary (for the grammatical completeness of the sentence) information that the toy has been made since 1902.

You could use a similar construction for your original sentence. 'The toy, built last year, was selected as the best'. [I have added the verb 'selected', because 'the best' is subjective, so a verb that communicates this fact is important, IMO.]

Answer (score 0):

"Was" seems very redundant and doesn't really have a flair in the sentence. I would suggest framing the sentence in the following way:

> The toy used to be the best and was built last year.

But sticking to your question, "was built" isnt really necessary once you write last year, since it clearly implies as something in the past to the reader. You can keep "was built" without much issues nonetheless.

Comment: What's the difference between redundant and very redundant? :)

Comment: Adding a degree to the redundancy of something, english on the flow!